# React: Import Js with from and curly braces part

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I am currently thinking of using "fabric-webpack" and looking at the demo using react "https://codesandbox.io/s/8k7kvwqx70?file=/src/index.js"

I under import { ... } from '....'

But not sure how this work if typing like this

import 'fabric-webpack'

Comment: you want to access fabric object??

Comment: yes i am trying to implement graphic tools using fabric but written inside a react application

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `import { fabric } from "fabric";` as shown [here](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js#install-with-npm)

The demo imports globally the library, that attaches the interface to `window`, `window.fabric`

Comment: Oh i see. what is different between context and window.fabric.

Comment: There are no differences unfortunately. The library is designed so that `fabric` gets bound to `window` either way. This doesn't make sense since I would expect `import { fabric } from "fabric";` to not produce any side effects against global object, `window`. I guess some compatibility limitations with some frameworks came on the developer's way